# New dataframe column conditional on existing column

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to make a heatmap of some survey results about local infrastructure projects. The survey asked people to predict what the main cost and main benefit of the project might be. I've already used ggplot to make a simple heatmap of costs and benefits. Now I would like to create a new "frequency" column in the dataset (see below) that normalizes based on the category total for each item in the "cost" column. So I'd like the first four items in "Frequency2" to be the corresponding item in the "Frequency" column divided by the total number of people who said Housing Prices were a major cost (61) and then multiplied by 100 to give a percent. Is there a quick way to do this in R? In Excel I'd use sumif to come up with category totals, and then I'd simply use an if statement to create the new column. Is there an analogous process in R? Thanks!

```
       Benefits    Costs         Frequency
14    Local Comp  Housing Prices    8
16          Jobs  Housing Prices   26
17         Other  Housing Prices    0
18          None  Housing Prices   27
20    Local Comp         Traffic    7
22          Jobs         Traffic   17
23         Other         Traffic    1
24          None         Traffic   11
```

**Data**

```
    df <- data.frame(Benefits=c("Local Comp", "Jobs", "Other", "None", "Local Comp", "Jobs", "Other", "None"),
Costs=c("Housing Prices", "Housing Prices", "Housing Prices", "Housing Prices", "Traffic", "Traffic", "Traffic", "Traffic"),
Frequency=c(8,26,0,27,7,17,1,11))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `ave` to calculate the Frequency sum per group. I do this inside `transform`:

```
transform(df, Frequency2 = Frequency / ave(Frequency, Costs, FUN = sum) * 100)
#     Benefits          Costs Frequency Frequency2
#14 Local_Comp Housing_Prices         8  13.114754
#16       Jobs Housing_Prices        26  42.622951
#17      Other Housing_Prices         0   0.000000
#18       None Housing_Prices        27  44.262295
#20 Local_Comp        Traffic         7  19.444444
#22       Jobs        Traffic        17  47.222222
#23      Other        Traffic         1   2.777778
#24       None        Traffic        11  30.555556
```

Or, if you have a very large data set, you could use dplyr for higher performance:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Costs) %>% mutate(Frequency2 = Frequency / sum(Frequency) * 100)
#Source: local data frame [8 x 4]
#Groups: Costs
#
#    Benefits          Costs Frequency Frequency2
#1 Local_Comp Housing_Prices         8  13.114754
#2       Jobs Housing_Prices        26  42.622951
#3      Other Housing_Prices         0   0.000000
#4       None Housing_Prices        27  44.262295
#5 Local_Comp        Traffic         7  19.444444
#6       Jobs        Traffic        17  47.222222
#7      Other        Traffic         1   2.777778
#8       None        Traffic        11  30.555556
```

Or using data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Frequency2 := Frequency / sum(Frequency) * 100, by = Costs ]
```

Comment: The `data.table` part is sneaky. You could save some key strokes by removing `by = `  btw

Comment: Haha! Imagine how much more time I would need to spend removing those 4 characters from my answer :D @DavidArenburg

Comment: It took me more time than @docendodiscimus but I came up with `df %>% group_by(Costs) %>% mutate(Frequency2 = Frequency / sum(Frequency) * 100)` as well

Comment: That would have made a nice answer, @StevenBeaupré. You'll learn to be faster.